# Allow only adding of column/table/view in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Suppose I have a platform which allows users to enter some SQL queries and execute them.
DB is Oracle 11.2

Is there any way to limit users' operations to CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW and ALTER table ADD COLUMN?

The only way I see is to parse all user provided queries with the grammar for Oracle DB 11.2. But this way is a very tedious one since there is no complete grammar in a free access (at least I couldn't find one) and implementing one will take days, if not weeks.

Comment: Are there aspects of the `alter table` syntax that you don't want them to be able to execute? Restricting to just those three DDL privileges isn't a problem; restricting within them would be.

Comment: Every aspect which alters existing columns or tables (aside from adding columns of course) has to be denied.

Answer (score 1):

Grant CREATE TABLE and CREATE VIEW privileges. 

 For ALTER TABLE, to limit just ADD COLUMN, it's possible to create procedure and grant EXECUTE:

```
create or replace add_column( tableName varchar2, columnDefinition varchar2 ) 
as
  execute immediate 'alter table '|| tableName || ' add column ' || columnDefinition; 
end;
/
```

(not tested)

and

```
GRANT EXECUTE on ADD_COLUMN to user2;
```

Comment: You should at least use [`dbms_assert`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm) to validate the parameters, to minimise the SQL injection possibilities. It isn't clear if the OP can make the users call a package instead of issueing DDL commands, but certainly worth considering.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can't replace "ALTER TABLE ADD" with a procedure. Also users must be able to use every possible clause in [add_column_clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_3001.htm#i2183462) so using dbms_assert would be rather difficult.